# Reverse and remove in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I can't finish this last question it's due in an hour

```
reverseDrop(L,R) :-
   reverseDrop(L,1,[],R).

reverseDrop([HL|TL],N,I,R) :-
   N = 1,
   reverseDrop(TL,0,[HL|I],R).
```

How can I complete this code, so it reverses the list and it removes 1 out of 2 element for instance:

```
?- reverseDrop([3,1,5,2,7,3],L).
L = [ 7, 5, 3 ].
true

?- reverseDrop(['world','a',' hello'],L).
L = [ 'hello', 'world' ].
true
```

Answer (score 0):

[As StackOverflow is not for doing homework or tests](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no one would do your question in the time, as we all end up doing each others class assignments! I asked the Prolog experts (the ones who have implemented it) and this little gem came back, and is shown for the benefit of later readers:

```
reverseDrop([],[]). %this can catch the empty list, when we have run out of data

reverseDrop([Keep|Rest1],Out):- %take the first item in the list off the main input list,
    append([_Drop],Rest,Rest1), %removes one item from what is left in the list, to be discarded
    reverseDrop(Rest,Reply), % recurse on the remainder
    append(Reply,[Keep],Out). % attach the First item to the end of the previous output
reverseDrop([Keep],[Keep]). % this is to catch when a list started with an odd number
```